# hidden download link by php language for my site

Tags: php

i want to hidden download link in php language.

for example->

example.com/index.php?file=file.exe

but my download show a complete path of my site folder directory.

plz help me.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing from your vague question, your index file is probably sending a `Location:` redirect header.

To hide the actual server path name, use an indirect download script:

```
<?php
   $file = basename($_GET["file"]);
   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
   ($file{0} != ".")
   and readfile("./downloads/dir/$file");
```

That's inefficient for big files and downloads. Commonly used anyway.